# I am trying to get serial port helper on VS code. It has installed but when ever I try and use it an error message shows that I don't understand?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When ever I try to press on the Serial port helper Icon it comes up with the following error message:

Initialization extension failed, you need to rebuild the extension, check it [here](https://github.com/imlinhanchao/vsc-serialport-helper/wiki/How-To-Build-SerialPort-Node-module). Or you can feedback [Issue](https://github.com/imlinhanchao/vsc-serialport-helper/issues/), provide your version information waiting to be updated.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong and can't find anything in terms how fix this?

I tried to open the extension because I was watching a video that showed me how to use it alongside a microbit he said something about changing a setting to a string but I didn't understand what he was talking about and so when I went to copy him it gave me an error message.